# Destiny transferring data

Tags: destiny

My brother started a character on destiny on my dads profile but now he has made his own profile an wants to play on his profile with that character even though he has made another character he still wants the other. Both profiles are on a home Xbox so is there any way he can play his character on his profile?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to transfer a destiny character between profiles unfortunately :(