# Can I save destiny progress to another xbox live account with a usb?

Tags: destiny

So, my xbox live account glitched out and I cannot enter in xbox live any more. I was wondering if I can use a usb or flash drive or what ever I can transfer data too, to save my destiny progress on another account. Is this possible?

Comment: Xbox live doesn't just "glitch out". Either you lock yourself out of your account, which contacting Microsoft support should help you with, or you have been banned, and the loss of your Destiny character is a penalty.

Comment: Before somebody points out the different console, [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231811/destiny-transferring-data) is the same question asked for xbox, that was pointed back to the other as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

No, Destiny saves are stored on their server. They are attached to your profile and are not able to be copied. You could contact Activision support if you want to keep trying.